# Using Promise.all to place Markers on Google Maps - Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, es6-promise

I have been trying to place Markers on coordinates on Google Maps for days now, but I run into this error:

*Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])*

So I found out that I can use `Promise.all` to solve this issue, but I am having trouble properly doing it. I am not completely sure how and where in my component I should be doing it.

Can anyone help me out?

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from "google-maps-react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getVacations } from "./redux";
import Geocode from "react-geocode";

class GoogleMaps extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      coords: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.getVacations();
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);

    const coordinates = this.props.vacations.map(coordinate => {
      const convert = Geocode.fromAddress(coordinate.location);
      return convert;
    })

    Promise.all(coordinates).then(locations => {
      const markers = locations.map(place => {
        console.log(place);
        const lat = place.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        const lng = place.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        return [
          <Marker
            key={place._id}
            position={
              {
                lat: lat, 
                lng:lng
              }
            }
            animation={2}
          />
        ]
      })
      this.setState({
        coords: markers
      })
    })

    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Map
          google={this.props.google}
          zoom={4} 
        >
          {this.state.coords}
        </Map>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const connectVaca = connect(state => ({vacations: state}), {getVacations})(GoogleMaps);

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
            apiKey: "API KEY HERE"
})(connectVaca)
```

Here's my getVacations action and the reducer:

```
export const getVacations = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.get("/vacations").then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type: "GET_VACATIONS",
                vacations: response.data
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
}

const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "GET_VACATIONS":
            return action.vacations;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have asynchronous function calls in your render method. The best place for asynchronous calls is `componentDidMount` as per the react documentation.

Place your `Promise.all` call into the `componentDidMount` function. Whenever your component mounts, this function will be executed. Then, whenever `setState` is called to set `coords`, your component will rerender with the updated `coords` values.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from "google-maps-react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getVacations } from "./redux";
import Geocode from "react-geocode";

class GoogleMaps extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      coords: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.getVacations();
    const coordinates = this.props.vacations.map(coordinate => {
      const convert = Geocode.fromAddress(coordinate.location);
      return convert;
    })
    Promise.all(coordinates).then(locations => {
      const markers = locations.map(place => {
        console.log(place);
        const lat = place.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        const lng = place.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        return (
          <Marker
            key={place._id}
            position={
              {
                lat: lat, 
                lng:lng
              }
            }
            animation={2}
          />
        )
      })
      this.setState({
        coords: markers
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Map
          google={this.props.google}
          zoom={4} 
        >
          {this.state.coords}
        </Map>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const connectVaca = connect(state => ({vacations: state}), {getVacations})(GoogleMaps);

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
            apiKey: "API KEY HERE"
})(connectVaca)
```

**Edit:** Since `loadVacations` is a thunk, you need to pass it to `dispatch`. Change your `mapDispatchToProps` function passed to `connect` like so:

```
const connectVaca = connect(
  state => ({vacations: state}),
  dispatch => {
    return { getVacations: () => dispatch(getVacations()) }
  }
)(GoogleMaps);
```

**Edit2:** It has to do with the fact that react runs an intial `render()` call once the page is loaded. Then, once your component is mounted, `componentDidMount` gets called. In `componentDidMount`, you run an asynchronous function `getVacations`. Since you're not waiting for your API call in `getVacations` to finish, the marker creation happens without any vacations loaded yet. Whenever you visit a new tab and go back to your application, `render` happens again with the loaded vacations from the previous API call which is why they show up.

Try returning a promise from your action `getVacations`. Then, whenever you call `getVacations` in `componentDidMount`, chain a `then` call to `getVacations`. Inside `then` is where you should place your coordinates creation + `Promise.all` call. Then I believe your code will work.

```
export const getVacations = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        // returning axios.get will return a promise you can chain a then call on
        return axios.get("/vacations").then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type: "GET_VACATIONS",
                vacations: response.data
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
}
```

Then in your `componentDidMount` function:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.getVacations().then(() => {
       // Place coordinates, your Promise.all call, and your setState call here 
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but this didn't work. The Markers still do not show up on the map. Even the `console.log(place)` inside of the `Promise.all` doesn't show up anymore.

Comment: @ChristianLopez It's because you're returning a `<Marker>` component inside of an array inside of your map function. Replace the `[ ]` with `( )` like I have in my edit and it should work.

Comment: @ChristianLopez Just noticed that `getVacations` is a redux action. Can you post the code for `getVacations` for me?

Comment: Hey, so switching the `[ ]` with `( )` worked, the Markers show up! Small issue though, when I refresh the page the Markers disappear. I have to go to another page and then click back to the page with the Map for it to show up again.

But the Markers show up, so thanks! This was getting a bit frustrating and you have helped me out a ton.

Comment: @ChristianLopez Can you post your `getVacations` action for me?

Comment: @ChristianLopez Try my edit and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Hey, it didn't work. Markers still disappear when page I refresh the page.

Comment: It's all right if you can't get it. I'll mark your answer as correct since you fixed what my original problem was.

Comment: @ChristianLopez One more suggestion

Comment: Yep, this fixed it. I am fairly new to React and Redux and I'm still getting a handle on all the important concepts. Everything you've done here has not only fixed my issue at hand, but I feel I have a better understanding of how to handle async operations. Again, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @ChristianLopez Glad I could help!